# duplicate menu items in GRUB

Tags: grub2, kubuntu

Just installed Kubuntu 16.04 last night, only to have it not include my Windows partition in GRUB. So I ran BootRepair and what happens next? My Windows partition comes back, but I now have duplicate menu items for it AND Kubuntu in GRUB. Typing **sudo update-grub** in the terminal didn't help as much as I thought it would either, tried that both before AND after running BootRepair.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **grub customizer**?

Here are the instructions for installation...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppstrong texta:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Give this thread a look! It's where I got this from. Maybe almost a duplicate, but not exactly.. not sure in this case.
[How to remove duplicate entries in Grub menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146743/how-to-remove-duplicate-entries-in-grub-menu)